# is it possible to publish matching getter and setter properties in polymer.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have been playing about with the stopwatch example from the polymer.dart tutorials. I've altered the `@Observable String counter = '00:00';` to:

```dart
String _counter = '00:00';
@published void set counter (String s){ _counter = s; }
@published String get counter => _counter;
```

I set it to `@published` so I can set the counter attribute in the html tag and this worked great when I initially just changed it to `@Published String counter = '00:00';` but having split it into separate getter and setter properties it no longer works at all, is it possible to do something like this? I want to have some custom logic performed when a bound value is changed either programmatically or via user/html changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@observable` is only necessary on the getter.

I guess what you want to do is

```dart
// additional functionality in the setter
String _counter = '00:00';
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) 
String get counter => _counter;
void set counter (String s){ 
  _counter = s;  
  // do something ...
}

void attached() {
  new async.Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds:1), (_) {
    var oldVal = _counter;
    var time = new DateTime.now();
    _counter = '${time.minute}:${time.second}';
    // explicitely notify Polymer about the changed value
    notifyPropertyChange(#counter, oldVal, _counter);
  });
}
```

or alternatively

```dart
// additional functionality in xxxChanged
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) 
String counter = '00:00';

void counterChanged(oldVal, newVal){ 
  // do something ...
}
```

another one is

```dart
// use readValue/writeValue to fix some timing issues
@PublishedProperty(reflect: true) 
String get counter => readValue(#counter);
void set counter (String s){ 
  writeValue(#counter, s); 
  // do something ...
}

//in the constructor
writeValue(#counter, '00:00');
```

`@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)` ensures that the HTML attribute gets updated with the field value.

If you find this confusing you are not alone ...

Comment: of the 3 solutions I can only get it to work if I use the middle one, and only if I set the field to `@published` I cant get any of them to work with `@PublishedProperty()`

Comment: I forgot something (`notifyPropertyChange`) in the first example but otherwise this worked for me. What Polymer version are you using?

Comment: Im using polymer 0.11.0+5

Comment: This is rather old. Current is 0.13.0+1

Comment: thanks I'll try upgrading, though its the version used by default in the polymer stopwatch example so it might be worth updating the example pubspec directly, do they have it on github?

Comment: I haven't found it. I asked here https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/CjzcjZGa8pU

Comment: Yep, it's here: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-tutorials-samples/tree/master/stopwatch (also added to the forum)